# Periodic DNS Fault

Tags: domain-name-system, hacking, domain-parking

I have a reseller account. but sometimes, somthings goes wrong on my websites. I think server is hacked or DNS server is hacked. I searched similar content on google, then I found same HTML codes on hacker websites.
Explaining the problem: mydomain.com is active everytime but sometime, floowing code is appeared. Please note that I have not this page or similar materials on account. Whether my domain contents is empty and only images folder is exist.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Welcome thisdomain.com</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/nobrand.css" type="text/css" />
<meta name="description" content="Web Hosting. Professional Web hosting services with free domain name, unlimited web hosting space and unlimited bandwidth." />
<meta name="keywords" content="web hosting, hosting, web host, host, website hosting, webhosting, web hosting provider, web hosting service, web hosting supplier, cheap web hosting, web space, web site hosting, web space hosting, best web hosting, cpanel hosting" />
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.top !== window.self) {document.write = "";window.top.location = window.self.location; setTimeout(function(){document.body.innerHTML='';},1);window.self.onload=function(evt){document.body.innerHTML='';};}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="frame center">
<div class="content">
<div class="header">
<div class="header_top">
<div class="header_c h_tl"></div>
<div class="header_c h_tr"></div>
<div class="header_c h_bl"></div>
<div class="header_c h_br"></div>
<div id="divider"></div>
<h1>This Domain is<br /><span class="bolden">PARKED.</span></h1>
</div>
</div><!-- class="header" -->

<div style="padding-bottom:12px"></div>

<div class="body_container">

<div class="body_container">

<style>
.icontent {
    width: 1025px;
    height: 700px;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.frame {
    width: 1065px;;
}

.header_top {
    width: 1025px;
}
#grad_break {
    left: 334px;
}
</style>

<script>
    var gaJsHost = ("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.";
    document.write("<scr"+"ipt src='" +gaJsHost+ "google-analytics.com/ga.js'></scr"+"ipt>");
</script>
<script>
    var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-9156498-1");
    pageTracker._initData();
    pageTracker._trackPageview("/parked/dns/thisdomain.com/%2F");
</script>

<center>
    <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="/ds_frame.html?a_id=115576" class="icontent"></iframe>
</center>

<hr class="bbar" />

</div>
</div><!-- class="content" -->
<div class="frame_c frame_br"></div>
<div class="frame_c frame_bl"></div>
</div><!-- class="frame center" -->
<div id="footer">
    <div id="copyright">&copy;2012. All rights reserved.</div>
</div><!-- footer -->

</body>
</html>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What is the domain, you may have your name servers for the domain misconfigured, so it sometimes goes to a server that is setup to show this page, while other times it goes to your production site.

Comment: Does not seem to be hacked, this is a standard "parking" site, and suggests more of a DNS problem. Maybe contact your hosting provider, if everything is OK on their end.

Comment: can you write your replies as answer? I want choose best answer but it is not possible for comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your A records on your registar's DNS configuration page and make sure they are pointing to the right place.

Comment: ns1 and ns2 ips for reseller account was pointed to wrong ip. It seems be solved.